# Naive Bayes Probabilistic Model in R

Tags: r, roc, naivebayes, knime

I have a Naive Bayes model on a models that have only nominal attributes.
The model is built in KNIME, and now I have to use it in R. 
Is there an automated way to classify with this model in R?
Or.. How it is the formula that gives to me the P(C=1|x1,,xn) given the Bayesian Table? I need the probability, not just a scoring function for the classification, so for me P(C=1)* P(x1|C=1) * .. * P(xn|C=1)  does not work.

Thanks to everybody.

Comment: Are not there PMML packages (like [pmml](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pmml/index.html)) for extracting information from the model? I think the KNIME model is just a PMML model without extensions.